# imprimir arrays por categoria con php

Tags: php, array, array-bidimensional

Tengo un problema que tal vez es simple de resolver, pero no doy con la solución, tengo dos array en php, uno tiene una lista de autos y el otro la lista de tipos, necesito imprimirlos en grupos organizados por su tipo, hasta ahí todo bien, pero necesito que si algún grupo no tiene autos asociados, que ese grupo no se imprima, en el caso del ejemplo, los de tipo suv no deberían imprimirse, pero si lo hacen porque están fuera de la condición:

```php
    $autos = array(
        0 => array(
            'categoria' => 'a02',
            'marca' => 'Toyota',
            'modelo' => 'Corolla'
        ),
        1 => array(
            'categoria' => 'a01',
            'marca' => 'Mazda',
            'modelo' => '3'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'categoria' => 'a01',
            'marca' => 'Toyota',
            'modelo' => 'Prius'
        ),
        3 => array(
            'categoria' => 'a02',
            'marca' => 'Nissan',
            'modelo' => 'Versa'
        ),
        4 => array(
            'categoria' => 'a01',
            'marca' => 'Nissan',
            'modelo' => 'Tiida'
        ),
        5 => array(
            'categoria' => 'a02',
            'marca' => 'Chevrolet',
            'modelo' => 'Sail'
        ),
        6 => array(
            'categoria' => 'a02',
            'marca' => 'Toyota',
            'modelo' => 'Yaris'
        )
    );

    $categorias = array(
        0 => array(
            'codigo' => 'a01',
            'tipo' => 'hatchback'
        ),
        1 => array(
        'codigo' => 'a02',
            'tipo' => 'sedan'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'codigo' => 'a03',
            'tipo' => 'suv'
        )
    );

    foreach($categorias as $categoria) {
        echo "<div class='container'>";
        echo "<h2>$categoria[nombre]</h2>";
        echo "<ul class='list-autos'>";
        foreach($autos as $auto) {
            if ($categoria[codigo] == $auto[categoria]) {
                echo "<li>";
                echo "<p>$auto[marca]</p>";
                echo "<p>$auto[modelo]</p>";
                echo "</li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

Comment: ¿Como es que obtenes los `$autos` y las `$categorias`? Si es con una consulta SQL, lo más simple seria modificar la consulta

Comment: el de los $autos es un array que me envían, el de $categorias lo hice yo con todas las categorías que tengo para cruzar la información, tal vez tengo mal resuelta la solución.. como dato extra el array de $autos no se debe modificar, el de $categorías si, existirá otra forma mejor cambiando el array de categorías??
gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Leyéndote, es casi seguro que no estás implementando la solución más óptima. Pulsa en [edit] y pon un pequeño ejemplo de ambos arrays, quizá podremos ayudarte a optimizar.

Comment: @A.Cedano es muy probable que no esté implementando la solución correcta, pues no conozco de php, los ejemplos de los array y el código que estoy usando para recorrer e imprimir los datos están en la pregunta. gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que puedes modificar el array `$categorias`, te propongo esta solución que consiste en comparar `$autos` contra `$categorias`, y cuando se encuentren valores coincidentes iremos llenando un sub-array con una clave `autos` en `$categorias`. Para eso usaremos el índice donde se encuentre esa categoría, que habremos recuperado previamente y guardado en la variable `$hasKey` al verificar si el valor existe.

Este es el código, creo que todo está explicado en comentarios:

```
#Comparamos $autos contra $categorias
foreach ($autos as $auto) {
    #Si el valor se encuentra en codigo, guardamos la key
    $hasKey=array_search($auto['categoria'], array_column($categorias, 'codigo'));
    #En esa key de $categorias guardamos marca y modelo desde $auto
    #y desechamos el dato 'categoria'  de $auto porque es redundante
        $categorias[$hasKey]['autos'][]=array('marca'=>$auto['marca'],'modelo'=>$auto['modelo']);
}


#Ahora podremos construir el contenido facilmente
#Concatenamos todo en esta variable para más claridad...
$mData="";

foreach ($categorias as $categoria){
    #Simplemente, cuando $categorias tenga una clave autos
    #significará que hay datos para mostrar
    if (array_key_exists('autos', $categoria)) {
        $mData.="<div class='container'>";
        $mData.="<h2>$categoria[tipo]</h2>";
        $mData.="<ul class='list-autos'>";
        foreach ($categoria['autos'] as $auto){
            $mData.= "<li>";
            $mData.= "<p>$auto[marca]</p>";
            $mData.= "<p>$auto[modelo]</p>";
            $mData.= "</li>";            
        }
        $mData.="</ul>";
        $mData.="</div>";
    }
}
#Imprimimos la variable
echo $mData;
```

**Salida:**

```html
<div class='container'>
  <h2>hatchback</h2>
  <ul class='list-autos'>
    <li>
      <p>Mazda</p>
      <p>3</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Toyota</p>
      <p>Prius</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Nissan</p>
      <p>Tiida</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <h2>sedan</h2>
  <ul class='list-autos'>
    <li>
      <p>Toyota</p>
      <p>Corolla</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Nissan</p>
      <p>Versa</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Chevrolet</p>
      <p>Sail</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>Toyota</p>
      <p>Yaris</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Como decía al principio, creamos en `$categorias` un sub-array con una clave `autos`, si haces un:

```
var_dump($categorias);
```

Podrás ver cómo quedó organizado el array, cada auto en su categoría:

**Salida:**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["codigo"]=>
    string(3) "a01"
    ["tipo"]=>
    string(9) "hatchback"
    ["autos"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["marca"]=>
        string(5) "Mazda"
        ["modelo"]=>
        string(1) "3"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["marca"]=>
        string(6) "Toyota"
        ["modelo"]=>
        string(5) "Prius"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["marca"]=>
        string(6) "Nissan"
        ["modelo"]=>
        string(5) "Tiida"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["codigo"]=>
    string(3) "a02"
    ["tipo"]=>
    string(5) "sedan"
    ["autos"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["marca"]=>
        string(6) "Toyota"
        ["modelo"]=>
        string(7) "Corolla"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["marca"]=>
        string(6) "Nissan"
        ["modelo"]=>
        string(5) "Versa"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["marca"]=>
        string(9) "Chevrolet"
        ["modelo"]=>
        string(4) "Sail"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(2) {
        ["marca"]=>
        string(6) "Toyota"
        ["modelo"]=>
        string(5) "Yaris"
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["codigo"]=>
    string(3) "a03"
    ["tipo"]=>
    string(3) "suv"
  }
}
```

Comment: La solución es perfecta, muchas gracias, se ajusta justo a lo que necesito, ayer había intentado algo similar, pero mis conocimientos son muy básicos.
muchas gracias por tu tiempo!!

Comment: @Marcelo me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Pues efectivamente lo que estas realizando es un ciclo sin validar previamente si existe la categoria, entonces la dibujas sin antes validar.

```
$autos = array(
    0 => array(
        'categoria' => 'a02',
        'marca' => 'Toyota',
        'modelo' => 'Corolla'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'categoria' => 'a01',
        'marca' => 'Mazda',
        'modelo' => '3'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'categoria' => 'a01',
        'marca' => 'Toyota',
        'modelo' => 'Prius'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'categoria' => 'a02',
        'marca' => 'Nissan',
        'modelo' => 'Versa'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'categoria' => 'a01',
        'marca' => 'Nissan',
        'modelo' => 'Tiida'
    ),
    5 => array(
        'categoria' => 'a02',
        'marca' => 'Chevrolet',
        'modelo' => 'Sail'
    ),
    6 => array(
        'categoria' => 'a02',
        'marca' => 'Toyota',
        'modelo' => 'Yaris'
    )
);

$categorias = array(
    0 => array(
        'codigo' => 'a01',
        'tipo' => 'hatchback'
    ),
    1 => array(
    'codigo' => 'a02',
        'tipo' => 'sedan'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'codigo' => 'a03',
        'tipo' => 'suv'
    )
);


foreach($categorias as $categoria) {
    $categoria["existe"] = false;
    foreach($autos as $auto) {
        if ($categoria["codigo"] == $auto["categoria"]) {
            if($categoria["existe"] != true){
                echo "<div class='container'>";
                echo "<h2>$categoria[tipo]</h2>";
                echo "<ul class='list-autos'>";
            }

            echo "<li>";
            echo "<p>$auto[marca]</p>";
            echo "<p>$auto[modelo]</p>";
            echo "</li>";

            if($categoria["existe"] != true){
                echo "</ul>";
                echo "</div>";
                $categoria["existe"] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prueba con el siguiente código, donde realiza la verificación de información antes de dibujarla.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu código funciona, pero solo deja el primer elemento que aparece dentro del ul, el resto lo deja fuera, pero por ahora creo que me sirve para avanzar, muchas gracias!